# skip some task with prompt in ansible

Tags: ansible

How can I access to answer one prompt on another server?
my hosts:

```
[dbs]
db1
db2
db3
```

I have one role and my `tasks/main.yml` is:

```
- pause:
   prompt: "Do you want to install mysql (yes/no)?"
  register: my_pause

- include_tasks: mysql.yml
  when: my_pause.user_input | bool
```

when I execute this role, only first server skip `MySQL.yml` and to another server execute `MySQL.yml`.

I want if the user enters no for answer prompt,‍‍`MySQL.yml` does not execute for any server. but when I enter no It will be installed again!!

```
 [root@anisble ansible]# ansible-playbook playbooks/test.yml 

PLAY [dbs] 
**************************************************************
    TASK [Gathering Facts] 
*******************
ok: [db1]
ok: [db3]
ok: [db2]

TASK [ssh : pause] ********************************************************************************
[ssh : pause]
Do you want to install mysql (yes/no)?:
no
  ok: [db1]

TASK [ssh : include_tasks] ********************************************************************************
skipping: [db1]
included: /etc/ansible/roles/ssh/tasks/mysql.yml for db2, db3

TASK [ssh : install mysql] ********************************************************************************
ok: [db3]
ok: [db2]

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************
db1                        : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
db2                        : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0   
db3
```

**Edited-1**

I use the first your solution but when I enter no It will be installed again!!

`task/main.yml`:

```
    ---
    - pause:
       prompt: "Do you want to install mysql (yes/no)?"
      register: install_mysql
      delegate_to: localhost

- include_tasks: mysql.yml
  when: hostvars['localhost']['install_mysql']['user_input'] == 'yes'
```

Output is :

```
[root@anisble ansible]# ansible-playbook playbooks/test.yml 
PLAY [dbs] ********************************************************************************
TASK [Gathering Facts] ********************************************************************************
ok: [db2]
ok: [db1]
ok: [db3]

TASK [ssh : pause] ********************************************************************************
[ssh : pause]
Do you want to install mysql (yes/no)?:
no
  ok: [db1 -> localhost]

TASK [ssh : include_tasks] ********************************************************************************
included: /etc/ansible/roles/ssh/tasks/mysql.yml for db1, db2, db3

TASK [ssh : install mysql] ********************************************************************************
  changed: [db1]
changed: [db3]
changed: [db2]

  PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************
    db1                        : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
    db2                        : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
    db3                        : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

**Edited-2**

This method works.

```
- name: confirm
  pause:
    prompt: "Do you want to install mysql (yes/no)?"
  register: install_mysql

- include_tasks: mysql.yml
  when: hostvars[groups['dbs'][0]]['install_mysql']['user_input'] == "yes"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Run pause on localhost

You can run the `pause` task on a specific host, eg `localhost` and get the answer from the hostvars array `hostvars['localhost']`([stolen from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161274/how-to-check-whether-an-item-is-present-in-an-ansible-array)).

```
- name: Pause prompt on localhost
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Prompt
      pause:
        prompt: "Do you want to install mysql (yes/no)?"
      register: install_mysql

- name: Get the answer from the hostvars array
  hosts: all  
  tasks:
    - name: Include role when you answered 'yes'
      include_tasks: mysql.yml
      when: hostvars['localhost']['install_mysql']['user_input'] == 'yes'
```

You have to use a dedicated play on that host to be able to access the answer in the hostvars array. If you run it once on a hostgroup (like in your original request), you have to guess which host will be processed first and use `hostvars['firstprocessedhost']` (sometimes `hostvars['db1']`).

When you use `delegate_to: localhost` the task is still run for `db1` and the answer is stored in `hostvars['db1']`.

You should not depend on the order of your hosts and the pause module is intended to pause a playbook not to prompt for user data.

## vars_prompt

If it's possible, you should use the `vars_prompt` section of your play:

```
- name: A play with a vars_prompt section
  hosts: all  
  vars_prompt:
    - name: install_mysql
      prompt: "Do yo want to install mysql (yes/no)?"

  tasks:
    - name: Include role when you answered 'yes'
      include_tasks: mysql.yml
      when: install_mysql == 'yes'
```

Comment: but is this a single choice that applies to all hosts? I think the question is about how to say yes or no for each individual hosts

Comment: In this case you cannot use `delegate_to`.

Comment: special thanks, @ctx. problem solved. I edited finally result ;)